# Devil's Throat: Djavolskoto Garlo - how could the child find out he was adopted?

Tags: plot-explanation, devils-throat-djavolskoto-garlo

One thing that's bothering me about [*Devil's Throat: Djavolskoto Garlo*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7710170) is how could the child who was adopted at the age of two years ever know that he was adopted and how could he figure out everything that his adopted father had done to his real parents? Especially that it was against the father's interest for the child to learn about that (no witnesses, no reports).

Was it ever explained in the final episode, or is it simply a hollywood moment (i.e. a plot hole)?